# What is a difference between PUSH/PULL and DEALER/ROUTER pattern in zmq?

Tags: python, zeromq

I have been learning **`zmq`** recently,
could someone brief me about
the difference between **`PUSH/PULL`** and **`DEALER/ROUTER`** pattern in `zmq`
and
when should I use which pattern?

Comment: I found this [http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html) very handy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [the **link** to `ZeroMQ` documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-socket) that describes all differnt types of sockets.

Basically **`PUSH/PULL`** are unidirectional. `PUSH` can only send and `PULL` can only receive.

**`DEALER/ROUTER`** are bi-directional and either `DEALER` or `ROUTER` can send/receive.